# Probability to destroy

Tags: probability

> The probability of a bomb hitting a bridge is $1/2$. Two direct hits are needed to destroy it. What is the least number of bombs required so that the probability of the bridge being destroyed is greater than $0.9$?

Selecting two bombs $\binom{n}{2}$

hence probability is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$ which should be greater than 0.9 from this I got $n=6$.
but answer is $7$

Comment: check the accepted answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747929/binomial-distribution-finding-the-number-of-trials-given-probability-and-succes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that a bomb will not hit the bridge is $1-\frac12=\frac12$.

The probability that of $n$ bombs, none hits the bridge is $\left(\frac12\right)^n$.

The probability that of $n$ bombs, exactly $1$ hits the bridge is $n\frac12\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}=n\left(\frac12\right)^n$.

So, the probability that the bridge is not destroyed is $1 - \left(\left(\frac12\right)^n+n\left(\frac12\right)^n\right) = 1 - (n+1)\left(\frac12\right)^n$.

$1 - (n+1)\left(\frac12\right)^n > 0.9$ gives  $(n+1)\left(\frac12\right)^n < 0.1$.

You can check that $7$ is the smallest positive integer that satisfies this inequality.

Comment: How you got n in $n(1/2)^n$

Comment: @Icandoahandstand99 $n$ ways to order $1$ bomb that hits the bridge and $n-1$ bombs that don't hit the bridge.

Answer (score 3):

1. Probability of all bombs missing the bridge is?
2. Probability of exactly 1 bomb hitting the bridge is?
3. Probability that neither (1) nor (2) happens is $p_n = ?$

Now, as you correctly mention, you need so find the least integer solution to $p_n > 0.9$, which is indeed 7.